# Can Point Cloud Library be used with iOS apps?

Tags: ios, point-cloud-library

I would like to port the arithmetic processing (written in C ++) using Point Cloud Library to an iOS application (swift). Is it possible to use PCL with swift?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported version of PCL compiled for arm64 yet. However, the following project may be useful:

https://github.com/patmarion/pcl-superbuild

It has difficulties with the current version of Boost for iOS, so you can replace Boost with a project like this:

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost/

Or maybe you can use the precompiled libraries from a project like this:

https://github.com/stevenroach7/3DScanr/tree/master/PCL_Build_Artifacts